# Motion detection using location of user not working properly

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the motion detection of user in my app by calculating its lat-long getting from googleAPIClient in which i am doing

1)get location of user in every 15 sec

2)the location before 15 sec and after 15 sec i am calculating the speed using formula mentioned below

```
`private double getSpeed(Location currentLocation, Location oldLocation) {
        if (currentLocation != null && oldLocation != null) {
            double newLat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            double newLon = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            double oldLat = oldLocation.getLatitude();
            double oldLon = oldLocation.getLongitude();
            if (currentLocation.hasSpeed()) {
                return currentLocation.getSpeed();
            } else {
                double radius = 6371000;
                double dLat = Math.toRadians(newLat - oldLat);
                double dLon = Math.toRadians(newLon - oldLon);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(newLat)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(oldLat)) *
                            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                double distance = ((Math.round(radius * c)) * 36) /1.609344;    // convert meter to km as m*60*60/s*1000 thn convert whole into miles;
                CommonMethods.showLogs("BaseActivity.this", "getSpeed distance == " + distance);
                double timeDifferent = (currentLocation.getTime() - oldLocation.getTime()) * 10; //convert mili sec to hr
                CommonMethods.showLogs("BaseActivity.this", "getSpeed time == " + timeDifferent);
                return distance / timeDifferent;
           }
        }
        return 0;
    }`
```

3) after that check if speed is more than 3mph than do my stuffs

4) it is working fine when tested in a car and bus but when tested in 2 
wheeler it is not working properly some times it is some time it is not

i don't get the problem what is wrong in my case please help!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Why does the method shown have anything to do with the type of vehicle you are in? Are you saying this method doesn't work, or that getting locations doesn't work, or that you aren't putting the right locations into this method?

Comment: The `Location` object already has a speed, so it's not necessary to calculate it yourself, unless you apply some sort of "fuzzy logic". GPS locations always have some error and fluctuation, so at slower speeds the user maybe doesn't move enough in 15 seconds for the error to be small enough proportionally to the actual displacement.

Comment: i am actually asking if i tested my code while sitting in a car & bus it gives me speed more than 3mph but when tested in a 2wheeler the same code is not giving speed 3mph speed or more than that .

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen yes but when i check it on log the location object gives 0 speed always that is the reason i am calculating it.

Comment: Maybe you use the device differently when on the bus/car or 2 wheeler. maybe you run into [background location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

Comment: @leonardkraemer no i am using the same device for testing. but i think it should be independent to the device i have tested if the code is same it should work in all cases right?

Comment: Or do you guys have anything else logic to get motion detection of device with respect to speed??

Comment: I mean that in one case the screen is on, in the other it is off (what device you are using does not matter, but how you are using it). With screen off your app goes in the background and you will not receive location updates any more, because of the background location limits.

Comment: @leonardkraemer i am testing it when app is in foreground.